# How do I compare two numbers for equality in Delphi?

Tags: c, delphi, if-statement

I'm converting a code from C to Delphi, but I'm stuck on the last line of this code:

```
 BOOL is_match = FALSE;
 unsigned int temp_val;
 unsigned int prev_val = 0;

 is_match = (temp_val == val);
```

I can only convert this much:

```
 var
  is_match: boolean;
  temp_val: cardinal;
  prev_val: cardinal;
 begin
  is_match := false;
  prev_val := 0;
  is_match := ????
 end;
```

How do I fill in the last assignment?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`is_match := temp_val = val;`

At any rate, I hope the code above is just a small excerpt of the real code, because `temp_val` is undefined at the time you compare it with `val`.

Answer (score 7):

The equality comparison operator in C is `==`. In Delphi the equivalent operator is `=`.

So you need to use this code:

```
is_match := temp_val=val;
```

---

Interestingly, as an aside, the C equality operator leads to a very classic and hard to spot bug. It goes like this:

```
if (x=0)
    DoSomething();
```

What happens here is that `=` is the assignment operator and so `x` is assigned a value of `0` which is then truth tested. And that returns false and so `DoSomething()` is never executed. I believe that this potential confusion is one of the reasons why Pascal chose to use `:=` for assignment.

Comment: Another reason is that the operator `==` looks funny. Indeed, in pure mathematics you don't write 'if a == 0 then the eigenvalues ...'. On the other hand, in mathematics, := is often used when you define a new quantity.

Comment: @Andreas Yes it took 74 seconds so I'm clearly on an off day.

Comment: C has '==' for equality, almost begging for developers to screw up, (I've done this more times than I can remember).  Delphi does not have this problem, but makes up for it with no warnings for 'myObject.create' instead of the desired 'myObject:=TmyObject.create' :((

Comment: myObject.Create invariably results in an immediate boom. That's easy to fix. if(x=0) can be much more invidious.